# How does DIG utility work in FreeBSD and BIND?

Tags: dns, bind, freebsd, named, dig

I want to know how does the DIG (Domain Information Groper) command really works when it comes to code and implementation. I mean when we enter a DIG command, which part of the code in FreeBSD or BIND hits first.

Currently, I see that when I hit the DIG command, I see the control going to a file [client.c](https://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/9.9.0rc1/bind-9.9.0rc1/bin/named/client.c). Inside this file, following function is called:

static void
client_request(isc_task_t *task, isc_event_t *event);

But how does the control reach to this place is still a big mystery for me even after digging a lot into 'named' part of the BIND code.

Further, I see this function being called from two places within this file. I tried to put logs into such places to know if control reaches to this place through those paths, but unfortunately that doesn't happen. It seems "Client_request()" function is somehow being called from outside somewhere that I am not able to figure out.

Is there anybody here who can help me out to resolve this mystery for me ?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking/debugging dig or named ? (dig just sends a DNS request over the network to the named server)

Comment: @nos I want to know where exactly the control reaches in named first while I give a 'dig' command. As I already explained, currently I see the control starting at "client_request()" function within the client.c file. But how exactly it reaches there and where from, I am not able to figure that out.

Comment: Your question is very vague. The URL you give as no relationship with `dig`, the command line (named and dig are two different things). Look instead at https://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/9.9.0rc1/bind-9.9.0rc1/bin/dig/dig.c  In any C program, the OS calls the `main` function first and then whatever happens there dictates the program flow. See line 1820 and later in previous link.

Answer (score 2):

Not only for `bind` but to any other command, within [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/) you could use [ktrace](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ktrace), it is very verbose but could help you to get a quick overview of how the program is behaving.

For example, in latest FreeBSD's you have [`drill`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=drill&sektion=1) command instead of `dig` so if you would like to know what is happening behind scenes when you run the command,  you could give a try to:

```
# ktrace drill freebsd.org
```

Then to disable tracing:

```
# ktrace -C
```

> Once tracing is enabled on a process, trace data will be logged until
>        either the process exits or the trace point is cleared.  A traced process
>        can generate enormous amounts of log data quickly; It is strongly
>        suggested that users memorize how to disable tracing before attempting to
>        trace a process.

After running  `ktrace drill freebsd.org` a file `ktrace.out` should be created the one you could read with [`kdump`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=kdump), for example:

```
# kdump -f ktrace.out | less
```

That will hopefully "reveal the mystery", in your case, just replace `drill` with `dig` and then use something like:

```
# ktrace dig freebsd.org
```

Comment: You could also do this with dig using the bind-tools port

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to FreeBSD Ports system you can compile your own BIND with debugging enabled. To do so run

```
cd /usr/ports/dns/bind913/ && make install clean WITH_DEBUG=1
```

Then you can run it inside debugger (`lldb /usr/local/bin/dig`), break on the line you are interested in and then look at backtrace to figure out how the control reached there.